# Does anyone know how to integrate Redis with Visual Studio for using with c++

Tags: c++, redis

I am new to Redis and want to use it in my application.
Have tried doing various steps from links across the web but not able to get it done,I need to send / receive strings to/ from redis db using c++..

If anyone knows any certain way or link where I can get the clear steps it will be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HiRedis is your best bet: https://github.com/redis/hiredis

It's a C client, so you might want to write some wrappers for convenience, but it's very solid. The downside is that it's not easiest to use asynchronously if you have to make more than a few calls.

I've also used cpp_redis: https://github.com/cylix/cpp_redis

It's easier to use, but last time I worked with it, it still had some bugs. It is in active development, however, so it likely to be better by now. It also comes with MSVC project, so it might make it a lot easier for you to integrate. If stability isn't crucial for your project, and integration time is, I'd give it a try.

Comment: Thank you i added cpp_redis and its working fine till now

Comment: we integrated cpp_redis to VisualStudio 2015, and it works using cpp_redis::future_client